# How to get playback status from silverlight media player (player.xap) thru javascript?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, video

I have a html page with embedded silverlight media player (player.xap). I want to get its playback status either thru events or by polling in javascript. Is that possible at all?

Cheers,
-K

Answer (score 0):

This **[link](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx)** will help you on how to call JS method from Silverlight, this can be useful in the things you want to achive. *Excerpt* from the link:

```
  HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);            
  HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("TalkToJavaScript", "Hello from Silverlight");
```